# How to get values from a dict into a new column, based on values in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary that contains all of the information for company ticker : sector. For example 'AAPL':'Technology'.

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
    ticker,dimension,calendardate,datekey,reportperiod,lastupdated,accoci,assets,assetsavg,assetsc,assetsnc,assetturnover,bvps,capex,cashneq,cashnequsd,cor,consolinc,currentratio,de,debt,debtc,debtnc,debtusd,deferredrev,depamor,deposits,divyield,dps,ebit,ebitda,ebitdamargin,ebitdausd,ebitusd,ebt,eps,epsdil,epsusd,equity,equityavg,equityusd,ev,evebit,evebitda,fcf,fcfps,fxusd,gp,grossmargin,intangibles,intexp,invcap,invcapavg,inventory,investments,investmentsc,investmentsnc,liabilities,liabilitiesc,liabilitiesnc,marketcap,ncf,ncfbus,ncfcommon,ncfdebt,ncfdiv,ncff,ncfi,ncfinv,ncfo,ncfx,netinc,netinccmn,netinccmnusd,netincdis,netincnci,netmargin,opex,opinc,payables,payoutratio,pb,pe,pe1,ppnenet,prefdivis,price,ps,ps1,receivables,retearn,revenue,revenueusd,rnd,roa,roe,roic,ros,sbcomp,sgna,sharefactor,sharesbas,shareswa,shareswadil,sps,tangibles,taxassets,taxexp,taxliabilities,tbvps,workingcapital
A,ARQ,1999-12-31,2000-03-15,2000-01-31,2020-09-01,53000000,7107000000,,4982000000,2125000000,,10.219,-30000000,1368000000,1368000000,1160000000,131000000,2.41,0.584,665000000,111000000,554000000,665000000,281000000,96000000,0,0.0,0.0,202000000,298000000,0.133,298000000,202000000,202000000,0.3,0.3,0.3,4486000000,,4486000000,50960600000,,,354000000,0.806,1.0,1086000000,0.484,0,0,4337000000,,1567000000,42000000,42000000,0,2621000000,2067000000,554000000,51663600000,1368000000,-160000000,2068000000,111000000,0,1192000000,-208000000,-42000000,384000000,0,131000000,131000000,131000000,0,0,0.058,915000000,171000000,635000000,0.0,11.517,,,1408000000,0,114.3,,,1445000000,131000000,2246000000,2246000000,290000000,,,,,0,625000000,1.0,452000000,439000000,440000000,5.116,7107000000,0,71000000,113000000,16.189,2915000000
A,ARQ,2000-03-31,2000-06-12,2000-04-30,2020-09-01,-4000000,7321000000,,5057000000,2264000000,,10.27,-95000000,978000000,978000000,1261000000,166000000,2.313,0.577,98000000,98000000,0,98000000,329000000,103000000,0,0.0,0.0,256000000,359000000,0.144,359000000,256000000,256000000,0.37,0.36,0.37,4642000000,,4642000000,28969949822,,,-133000000,-0.294,1.0,1224000000,0.493,0,0,4255000000,,1622000000,0,0,0,2679000000,2186000000,493000000,29849949822,-390000000,-326000000,2000000,-13000000,0,-11000000,-341000000,95000000,-38000000,0,166000000,166000000,166000000,0,0,0.067,1010000000,214000000,572000000,0.0,6.43,,,1453000000,0,66.0,,,1826000000,297000000,2485000000,2485000000,296000000,,,,,0,714000000,1.0,452271967,452000000,457000000,5.498,7321000000,0,90000000,192000000,16.197,2871000000
A,ARQ,2000-06-30,2000-09-01,2000-07-31,2020-09-01,-6000000,7827000000,,5344000000,2483000000,,10.821,-222000000,703000000,703000000,1369000000,155000000,2.129,0.597,129000000,129000000,0,129000000,361000000,146000000,0,0.0,0.0,238000000,384000000,0.144,384000000,238000000,238000000,0.34,0.34,0.34,4902000000,,4902000000,27458542149,30,19.97,-153000000,-0.338,1.0,1301000000,0.487,0,0,4743000000,,1762000000,0,0,0,2925000000,2510000000,415000000,28032542149,-275000000,-181000000,42000000,31000000,0,73000000,-417000000,-15000000,69000000,0,155000000,155000000,155000000,0,0,0.058,1091000000,210000000,783000000,0.0,5.719,46.877,44.2,1581000000,0,61.88,2.846,2.846,2167000000,452000000,2670000000,2670000000,318000000,,,,,0,773000000,1.0,453014579,453000000,461000000,5.894,7827000000,0,83000000,238000000,17.278,2834000000
```

I would like to have my dictionary match up with all the tickers in the CSV file and then write the corresponding values to a column in the CSV called sector.

Code:

```
for ticker in company_dic:
    sf1['sector'] = sf1['ticker'].apply(company_dic[ticker])
```

The code is giving me problems.

For example, the first sector is healthcare, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Healthcare is an unknown string function
```

Would appreciate some help. I'm sure there's a pretty simple solution for this. Maybe using iterrows()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [`.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), not [`.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) to select values from a `dict`, by using a column value as a `key`, because `.map` is the method specifically implemented for this operation.

  - `.map` will return `NaN` if the ticker is not in the `dict`.
- `.apply` can be used, but `.map` should be used

  - `df['sector'] = df.ticker.apply(lambda x: company_dict.get(x))`
  - `.get` will return `None` if the ticker isn't in the `dict`.

```py
import pandas as pd

# test dataframe for this example
df = pd.DataFrame({'ticker': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL'], 'dimension': ['ARQ', 'ARQ', 'ARQ'], 'calendardate': ['1999-12-31', '2000-03-31', '2000-06-30'], 'datekey': ['2000-03-15', '2000-06-12', '2000-09-01']})

# in your case, load the data from the file
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

# display(df)
  ticker dimension calendardate     datekey
0   AAPL       ARQ   1999-12-31  2000-03-15
1   AAPL       ARQ   2000-03-31  2000-06-12
2   AAPL       ARQ   2000-06-30  2000-09-01

# dict of sectors
company_dict = {'AAPL': 'tech'}

# insert the sector column using map, into a specific column index
df.insert(loc=1, column='sector', value=df['ticker'].map(company_dict))

# display(df)
  ticker sector dimension calendardate     datekey
0   AAPL   tech       ARQ   1999-12-31  2000-03-15
1   AAPL   tech       ARQ   2000-03-31  2000-06-12
2   AAPL   tech       ARQ   2000-06-30  2000-09-01

# write the updated data back to the csv file
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=Fales)
```

Answer (score 0):

temp = sf1.ticker.map(lambda x: company_dic[str(x)])  (#faster than for loop)
sf1['sector'] = temp

You can pass na_action='ignore' if you have NAN's in tickers column